# django access local testing url

Tags: django, windows-xp, push-notification

I am running windows xp and django 1.2.1 locally.  I was wondering if there is a way to allow outside applications to be able to access a url in my local app.

For example I would like the url: http://www.127.0.0.1:8000/my-url to be able to receive push notifications from a webapp while I am working locally.  It's a pain to have to upload my code to a server just to do testing on this one thing everytime I make a simple change.

Thanks for the insight and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by starting your application using

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:8000
```

replace `192.168.1.1` with your system IP.

all the systems on your local network will be able to access your application, http://192.168.1.1:8000

If you want your application to be accessible from systems outside of your network, you need to have a static IP that is is accessible from outside world.

Comment: You don't really need a static IP, you could use some DDNS (like dyndns or noip). Anyway, all you need is port forwarding from your router to your local machine.